# The parameter data type of UInt32 is invalid. (MS SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In general we are supposed to pass integer values to our stored procedures and to do so we usually do it with this method

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", paramValue);
```

But, I found it very strange that if we need to pass uint datatype parameter to the stored procedure using above method, it gives a strange exception. Although its not when the code hits the `ExecuteNonQuery` method, but its after that. I am not sure why this is happening. If anyone have anything to share please...

Here's the stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, Object value, Boolean inferLen, Boolean streamAllowed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: we are not superman so please post your error

Comment: I would personally avoid `AddWithValue` and instead use `Add`, specifying the parameter type (e.g. `SqlDbType.Int`) and then set the `Value` property.  That makes it clear what type you really want to go to the database.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) provided `UInt32` is not supported in Sql.

> Inferring a `SqlDbType` from `UInt32` is not supported.

So it is good to pass parameter as;

```
command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(paramValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", SqlDbType.Int));
```

You can check this [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types-ado-net/) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`UInt16` is not supported in ADO.NET. Use `Int64` instead of `UInt16`. For more information visit:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it like `string`. Use `UInt32.ToString()`. It's work perfectly.